# Corda generateSpend pay coins add memo

Tags: corda

Hi Is there a way to use `Cash.generateSpend` and allocate a message memo together with it?

My use case is simple, where when i spend the case i would like to tag the cash into some generic categories for example, manually-transferred or auto-transferred to a specific party.
I've been going through https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.finance.contracts.asset/-cash/index.html but there were no methods to add a tagging to the asset transferred purpose.

The main purpose is so when i query my history transactions i could see the movement of my funds.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a note to any transaction from within a flow as follows:

```
serviceHub.vaultService.addNoteToTransaction(
    theTransactionToAddANoteTo.id, 
    "The note to add to the transaction."
)
```

If you want, you can add multiple notes to the same transaction.

You can then view the notes associated with a given transaction from within a flow:

```
serviceHub.vaultService.getTransactionNotes(
    theTransactionToGetNotesFor.id
)
```

You can also log directly into your node's database and check the contents of the `VAULT_TRANSACTION_NOTES` table.

Comment: Hi Joel, if i would want to have a note that is on both parties ( sender and receiver ) how would i be able to do that?

Comment: Just write both the sender and receiver flows to add a message to the transaction. If that's not possible, you'd have to look at storing the message somewhere in a transaction. If so, could you raise a new question explaining why you'd want to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a custom SQL query to join the two tables (using the transaction id as join key) - vault_states/vault_fungible_states and vault_transaction_notes - by using the serviceHub.jdbcSession().

Please fee free to add a Feature Request if you would like us to extend the Vault Query API to provide a query criteria method to perform this automatically. Please add here:
https://github.com/corda/corda/issues